# When a Linux (Ubuntu) system shuts down, which processes get sent a SIGTERM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown, signals

If I start an ongoing background process A which starts a child process B, and I ask the OS to shut down, which processes get sent a SIGTERM? Is it both A and B or is it just A (assuming that A should be responsible for shutting down B)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question refers to Ubuntu Xenial (other versions may differ).

The manual for [`shutdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/shutdown.8.html) says *all*:

> ***All*** processes are first notified that the system is going  down
> by the signal `SIGTERM`.  This gives programs like `vi(1)` the time to save the file being edited, mail and news processing programs  a  chance  to exit  cleanly,  etc.

There is no specified order; your programs should be prepared for either parent or child process to receive a `SIGTERM` first.  Normally there is a delay after receiving the signal (but it is not required).

Comment: Note: The manual for shutdown no longer says this.